Restrict Kivy FileChooserListView to use double-click to open folder
I'm using Python's Kivy FileChooserListView in a popup, and I want it to require you to double click a folder to open it more like in Windows, but I cannot figure out how to do it.
The problem is that if you click a button to open the ListView, sometimes it clicks through to the folder and begins navigating before you even have a chance to let up on the mouse.
Overriding the on_touch_down method doesn't seem to work, nothing does. Any ideas how to make it require a double-click to open a folder?
